# Detect Wheel Collision Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car in my scene that has Wheelcollider attached to it's wheels, I want to detect when the wheels collide with another object (with box collider and rigidbody component), I tried attaching the script bellow to the wheels but it didn't detect the collision, I've also tried attaching it to the object, but it didn't succeed, how can I solve this?

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wheel"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided");
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable Gizmos in the Editor and tell me if you can see the collider on the wheels in the Scene view.

Comment: @Eric, Yes I can see the wheels colliders in scene view

Comment: If you add this script to the wheel then you should not check that the thing you collide with is wheel. Does the Debug.Log not trigger if you move it outside the if statement?